# Просмотр компьютеров в локальной сети из терминала Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Полный чайник в Linux. Как посмотреть из терминала все компьютеры, которые подключены к локальной сети ?

Поясню подробней. Интернет-кабель у меня подключен к роутеру. От роутера идет несколько кабелей к компьютерам с Ubuntu. А теперь сам вопрос... Как мне с одного из этих компьютеров увидеть остальные компьютеры внутри сети роутера ?

Comment: А с какой целью интересуетесь ? Т.е. что вы понимаете под "компьютером подключенным к локальной сети". Вам их ip/mac адресов достаточно или вы ждете чего то большего

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to find all the used IP addresses on a network](https://askubuntu.com/q/224559/3712)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что имеется в виду, но предложу варианты (маску подставить по необходимости):

1. `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` (при блокировке ICMP файрволом можно попробовать другие варианты, например, UDP: `nmap -sn -PU 192.168.0.0/24` )
2. `echo 192.168.0.{1..254}|xargs -n1 -P0 ping -c1|grep "bytes from"` (это те, кто на пинг отвечает)

Comment: Уточнил свой вопрос...

Answer (score 3):

Для начала убедитесь, что установлена samba. Если такой пакет присутствует и задана рабочая группа, выполните в консоли

```
nmblookup '*'
smbtree -N
```

Comment: а как убедиться, что samba стоит на разыскиваемых компьютерах?

Comment: samba должна стоять на компьютере, с которого идет поиск. На разыскиваемых можно посмотреть, отктрыт ли порт 139 tcp.

Comment: но для того, чтобы «посмотреть», надо знать ip-адрес. получается рекурсия.

Comment: Сканируйте сеть, проверяйте открыт ли порт. Я привел в ответе вариант для обычной одноранговой сети. Должно работать как в windows (компьютеры сети)

Answer (score 3):

Есть очень удобная утилитка `fping` http://fping.org/
Прямо-таки для этого создана. Можно `nmap`, но это будет гораздо медленнее.

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю ещё варианты.

```
$ avahi-browse -r -a
```

Как и nmblookup он требует, чтобы на компьютерах была установлена соответствующая служба, для linux это `avahi-daemon`. (С нашими тупыми провайдерами рекомендую всегда отключать проверку на использование домена *.local*: в `/etc/default/avahi-daemon` поставить `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0`)

Широковещательные пинги:

```
$ ping -b 255.255.255.255
```

Чтобы компьютер с linux отвечал на это, нужно сделать на нём:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=0
```

Некоторые маршрутизаторы это так же поддерживают.

Ну и более низкоуровневый и как мне кажется более надёжный для односегментной сети:

```
$ echo 192.168.2.{1..254} | xargs -n1 -P0 arping -c 4 -f -I eth0 | grep "reply from"
```

Comment: кстати, тут уже неоднократно насоветовали (другие отвечающие) отправлять icmp-запросы. а ведь подключенные к сети компьютеры вполне могут и не отвечать на такие запросы.

Comment: Тот же nmap позволяет отправлить не только ICMP

Comment: Ну если кто-то не хочет, чтобы его обнаружили, он всегда может это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Так проще и выдаст IP, сетевое имя и MAC-адрес:

```
nbtscan 192.168.0.1-255
```